# NextJs 11 to 13 Upgrade caused problem on Redux

Tags: next.js

I got a Next 11 project and will be upgrading to Next13. My problem is that in the dev mode, selectors can't access the updated states but it dispatches correctly.

When I build the project it runs well though. Has anyone encountered this too?

Thank you so much for the help in advance.